# Build Buck failed in M1 chip

Tags: apple-m1, buck

I try to install buck using homebrew and source code to build

In homebrew installation was encounter that cannot install openJdk@8 because it didn't support M1 chip.

Therefore I was installed azul java8

```
1.8.0_312 (arm64) "Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 8.58.0.13" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And try to build buck (ant)

But there is the error message.

```
javac-plugin:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/even/buck/ant-out/javac-plugin/classes
    [javac] [compiled 515 lines in 381 ms: 1351.7 lines/s]
    [javac] [4 .class files generated]
      [jar] Building jar: /Users/even/buck/ant-out/javac-plugin/javac-plugin.jar
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/even/buck/ant-out/classes/com/facebook/buck/jvm/java/plugin

report-generator-jar:
      [jar] Building jar: /Users/even/buck/ant-out/report-generator.jar

create-classpath:

create-classpath-hash:
   [delete] Deleting: /Users/even/buck/ant-out/classes/META-INF/buck-binary-hash.txt
     [echo] Generated Buck hash: ad0b5925588b10541e7be7b16386cd6f

gen-buck-info:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/even/buck/build.xml:1074: exec returned: 137
```

Does anyone has experience? Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SDKMAN https://sdkman.io. I can assure you that Liberica JDK 8 installs smoothly on M1

sdk install java 8.0.312-librca

Comment: or check alternative installation methods https://bell-sw.com/pages/package-managers/#sdkman

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).